# オートコミットについて

Tags: php, mysql, database

プログラミング初心者です。

データベースの更新ができず他の方のエラー解決策を拝見していたのですが、オートコミットが原因であったという声がありました。

調べてみたのですがいまいちつかめず。
autocommitとうのを設定しておくと、どこからでもデータベースの書換が可能ということでしょうか？

Comment: 更新ができないのと、オートコミットは、直感的には関係なさそうな気がします。まずは、「更新できない」という現象を詳細に書いてみてください。また、可能なら該当する部分のプログラムコードを質問に追記してみてください。言葉よりもコードのほうが、詳しい人からコメントが付きやすくなるかもしれません。

Comment: オートコミット関係ありませんでした。もう一度プログラム見直したところ更新とは関係ない部分で処理が正しくなされていなかったため、更新できなかったようです。次回からコードも入れて質問するように致します。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

更新をするコード自体はあっていたようです。
エラー表示の設定で$error[]を配列にしてそれぞれメッセを表示するようにしていました。
$error[name]="名前が入力されていません。";
$error[mail]="メールアドレスが入力されていません。";
のようにそれぞれ設定。
全ての入力がされていた場合
if(count($error)===0){//正しい時の処理}

しかしcountができていないませんでした。
$error=[];と最初につけ解決しました。

更新自体のプログラムではなく、その前後に組み込んでいたエラー処理が原因でした。

Answer (score 1):

違います。オートコミットとは、SQLを実行すると自動的にコミット（変更を確定）することです。

データベースの更新ができないのであれば、まずはアプリのログをみてください

Comment: ありがとうございます。現在PHPファイルから、データベースの書換、更新をしようとしています。データベースのautocommitというのがonの状態であれば、更新できる可能性が高いということでしょうか。

Comment: 実装次第なのでなんとも言えません。オートコミットが有効で、更新SQLがエラーになっていなければ、少なくともそのSQLの発行直後は、データが更新されています。その後、他のクライアントがさらに更新SQLを発行したら、上書きされますが。